# Call Google Cloud Function which requires authentication via Service Account from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

Setup:

- The official and latest (v43) OAuth2 library was added to Google Apps Script
- The Google Apps Script script is linked to the same GCP project as the Cloud Function is hosted
- The Service Account was created within the same GCP project
- The Service Account has the following roles: Owner, Logs Writer, Cloud Functions Admin, Cloud Functions Invoker
- A JSON key file was created for the Service Account and copied into the script

Problem:

- The response is always: "401 Error: Unauthorized Your client does not have permission to the requested URL"

Steps already tried out:

- I was able to call the Cloud Function when unauthenticated invocations were allowed
- I have tried to use the JWT methods from the OAuth2 library, but the error response is the same
- Ask ChatGPT to write my code, still the same error and the code is quite similar to mine

Code:

```
      const serviceAccount = {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "xxx",
        "private_key_id": "xxx",
        "private_key": "xxx",
        "client_email": "xxx",
        "client_id": "xxx",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "xxx",
        "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
      };

      const createService = (name, serviceAccount, scopes) => {
        return OAuth2.createService(name)
          .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
          .setPrivateKey(serviceAccount.private_key)
          .setIssuer(serviceAccount.client_email)
          .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
          .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
          .setLock(LockService.getUserLock())
          .setScope(scopes);
      };
      
      const sendRequest = (url, oauthParams) => {
        const { serviceName, serviceAccount, scopes } =
          oauthParams;
      
        const oauthService = createService(
          serviceName,
          serviceAccount,
          scopes
        );
      
        if (!oauthService.hasAccess()) {
          console.log(oauthService.getLastError());
          return;
        }
      
        const headers = {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${oauthService.getAccessToken()}`,
        };
      
        const options = {
          method: 'get',
          headers,
          muteHttpExceptions: true,
        };
      
        return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
      };
      
      const callCF = () => {
        const url = 'xxx';
        const oauthParams = {
          serviceName: 'GWMservice',
          serviceAccount,
          scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
        };
      
        console.log(sendRequest(url, oauthParams));
      };

      callCF();
```

Comment: App Script is designed to work with user identities, not technical accounts. What's your use case? Why do you need to use a service account?

Comment: It will be a public addon, so I can not use the user's account to fetch the data. The addon needs to call an API to generate a token. I would like to secure this endpoint

Comment: Why adding security where anyone can use it?

Comment: Anyone can use the addon, but only one user should be allowed to call the endpoint. It is a public API which generates a security token. The users of the addon are not able to call the API, it is done in the backend.

Comment: So, what's your security chain? You have public users (anyone), that can use a public addon to generate a security token. But what's the validity of this security token if anyone can generate it? If the user is not authenticated by Google Cloud (no Google account), you have to implement your own authentication service. This service must be public (because you have no Google Credential) and perform the sec check in the service. And after, you will be able to use your service account. But I think you must clarify the chain, the risk and what you want to avoid first.

Comment: So it means it is just not possible? Or is it possible to change the code to make it work?

Comment: Things are possible, but I'm not sure about what to protect and against what!

Comment: If you know, please share the code.

Comment: For doing what?? I'm sorry, but I still don't know what to achieve!

Comment: I want to call a Google Cloud Function which requires authentication via a Service Account from Google Apps Script. I want to avoid that the Cloud Function is called from somewhere else than my GAS backend.

Comment: Something like that? https://medium.com/google-cloud/call-cloud-run-from-app-script-the-easy-way-70677086efa1

Comment: Yes this is the direction I am looking for. There is only one thing: "... The Service Account Token Creator role granted on the App Script user ...". As it is going to be a public addon I can not grant this role to everyone, so I would need to use a key file.

Comment: Again, if it's public, why do you need security? If you put a door in your house to secure it, and let anybody enter, why did you put this door? What do you want to secure? To avoid which risk?

Comment: The response from the API will only be displayed to the GAS backend and not the user / frontend. So there is no door.

Comment: Ok, like an API Gateway, to filter and format correctly the data, but not really for security

Comment: Yes it is also used for these things.